# C# populate combobox with XML data based on another combobox

Tags: c#, xml

Total noob when it comes to XML here, I've got an XML file with the structure as follows:

```
<Error_Codes>
   <Test_1>
     <Code>ABC</Code>
     <Description>Item #1</Description>
   </Test_1>
   <Test_1>
     <Code>DEF</Code>
     <Description>Item #2</Description>
   </Test_1>
   <Test_2>
     <Code>UVW</Code>
     <Description>Item #3</Description>
   </Test_2>
   <Test_2>
     <Code>XYZ</Code>
     <Description>Item #4</Description>
   </Test_2>
```

What I want to do is have the user select either Test 1 or Test 2 from a previous ComboBox, then populate the 2nd ComboBox (let's call it codeCBO) with the values in the `<Test 1>` portion of the XML file, ideally with each item in codeCBO structured like `Code-Description`.  I looked online and see there are a lot of XML tutorials, but I don't see anything like what I'm trying to do.  Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

For some reason the Error_codes end tag does not show up here, but it is in the XML file I'm working with

Comment: That's not even valid XML. If that is actually the format you are working with and not a copy/paste error then you won't find an XML API to help you obtain the data.

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't include the '_' character for spaces, and I forgot the '</Error_codes>' at the end. Aside from that, what else are you referencing as "not valid XML?" Visual Studio doesn't find an error in the XML file with the stuff I forgot included

Comment: Ah I do see a copy error. I'll revise the top post with what I really have (had to rewrite to not include work sensitive stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with this for 3 days, I finally found the solution that worked for me.  XML file now looks like this:

```
<Error_Codes>
   <Test1 code="0001" description="test ABC"/>
   <Test1 code="0002" description="test DEF"/>
   <Test2 code="9999" description="test UVW"/>
   <Test2 code="8888" description="test XYZ"/>
</Error_Codes>
```

Then, my C# code looks like this:

```
 private void stationCBO_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     codeCBO.Items.Clear();
     LoadXML(stationCBO.Text);
 }

private void LoadXML(string station)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Failure_Modes.xml");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == station))
            {
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    string text = reader.GetAttribute("code") + "-" + reader.GetAttribute("description");
                    codeCBO.Items.Add(text);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```